# MSTest does not execute unit tests

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest, vs-unit-testing-framework

When I try to run my unit tests, either in the Visual Studio 2010 IDE or from the commands line (via `mstest /testcontainer:my.dll`), I get this error:

> Failed to queue test run 'kootsookosp@TFSSERVER 2011-06-28 11:00:11': Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Agent
>   .AgentProcessManager.SetCurrentPlatform(System.Reflection.ProcessorArchitecture, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.AssemblyClr
>   Version)'.

[Most other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525578/why-are-all-my-visual-studio-test-results-not-executed) regarding `mstest` errors suggest an issue with security, but this seems different.

Googling the above error message doesn't appear to show anything much that seems relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `my.dll` 64 bits? MSTest does not support that.

Comment: It is 64-bits, but it seems to be a difference between the RTM and SP1 releases of Visual Studion 2010. The RTM doesn't run correctly, the SP1 version does work correctly.

Comment: According to the docs MSTest does not support the testing of 64 bit assemblies. Reads this article (it refers to the agent too!) http://rupertrawnsley.blogspot.com/2011/04/mstest-and-64bit.html

Comment: Interesting blog.  It doesn't seem to be the issue I'm seeing: as I said, on one machine with RTM it doesn't work, but on the other machine with SP1 it does work correctly.  I need to wait to update the RTM machine. Once I've done that I'll check back in here.

Comment: If the dll contains 64 bit code the fact that MSTest is able to test it might be occasional and not something to rely on.

Comment: ?? Non-deterministic compiler behavior sounds strange... though now hat you mention it, I'll check the OS versions of the two machines also, that might give a clue.

Comment: MSTest is not a compiler but an executer of tests.

Comment: The compiler is what is producing the DLL, and it sounded like you were implying that the 64-bit code generated by the compiler differed. Apparently I got the wrong end of the stick.

Comment: MSTest does not support the testing of 64-bit dlls as I stated before. What happens when you try to test a 64-bit dll, I don't know.

Comment: You keep asserting that, but I don't believe it is the issue in the case I am asking about. I can run MSTest in both the IDE and command line on several 64-bit machines, just not on one specific 64-bit machine.

Comment: That is new information you'd better investigate the differences between the machines. Yes, MSTest will run on a 64-bit OS but it will not test 64-bit dlls. (I will stop repeating that ;-) )