# Tests not executed in Visual Studio 2010 after installing 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I might have done something wrong, but not quite sure what. I've been using VS 2010 and I wanted to install 2012 and use the same solution there.

What I have done is basically just install SQL 2012 and then VS 2012 (new instance, not upgrade) and then I opened then same solution I've been using in VS 2010 in VS 2012. Everything seems to be working, and I'm able to build and run tests (even though some tests that passed in 2010 are now failing in 2012 for some reason).

However, I wanted to run the same tests in VS 2010 and so I opened the same solution there. Everything also seems fine there and I'm able to build. The problem is that whenever I try to run tests, they just fail with Not Executed right away. No error message given. I've tried restarting VS, rebuilding, building, but it doesn't help. This leads me to think I've done something wrong at some point.

Does anyone have any idea? Feel free to ask if something is not clear and I'll try to explain (I am not an expert but I'll do my best).

Edit: It looks like my test settings was changed somehow. I'm able to run now after changing back to Local (and setting the host to run on 64 bit, even though I'm not sure that was really needed).

(Any way of setting a question to solved? Couldn't find the option for it.)

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue I got some months back. The visual studio IDE did not show any error.
This link is what helped me fix the problem : [Why are all my Visual Studio test results "Not executed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525578/why-are-all-my-visual-studio-test-results-not-executed)

Comment: Thanks, I can see some warnings and errors when clicking the Test run error link in the IDE. Doesn't make a lot of sense to me right now, but I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758204/tests-are-no-longer-executed-through-visual-studio-2010-after-visual-studio-11-b) which is a [known issue for MS](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/728659/mstest-not-working-after-installing-vs11-next-to-vs10).

You have to install [Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691).

Comment: Thanks, but I have that. It's been working as smoothly as a baby's buttocks, and it wasn't until I installed VS 2012 it started to fail.